# How to use RazorEngine in an Azure environment (worker role)?

Tags: azure, xslt, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, razorengine

I am using **RazorEngine v3.8.1**. My application needs to send out thousands of emails each day (between 5,000 and 50,000 on any given day). I am amazed at the simplicity of the RazorEngine (http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/) but am challenged with a few issues. My questions are:

**1) Is using Engine.Razor threadsafe?** As far as I can tell it is. I have an Azure queue and pop off a number of messages at a time, and spin off each one as a new task, so if it's not then I don't believe this will work for me.

**2) It seems the templates are cached and cannot be deleted without either running the code outside of the default app domain, or to manually delete the templates periodically. In an Azure worker role how can I delete these templates periodically?** I'm not sure I'd know how to access the proper temp folder in an Azure context.

As much as I love using this RazorEngine framework, I'm starting to wonder if perhaps XSLT may be less headache in the long run.

Comment: Instead of trying StackOverflow for all your needs, you can consult the documentation of the library you use. For example here: http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateManager.html

Comment: I've been over the documentation multiple times. I don't understand how to apply some of their suggestions in an Azure context. Nor do I feel like running my entire worker role app in another app domain just for this simple templating piece. Also, a lot more people hang around on StackOverflow. I find it likely that more people who have used tools like this in the past will be on SO more often that revisiting the documentation/site they may have used once or twice in the past.